Bootstrap on samples with different precision
Imagine the following setup:

I have N specimens that come from the same population (e.g., they are from the dame material)
For each specimen i, I have a single estimate of a given property in terms of its mean value $x_i$ and a confidence interval $[x_i-CI_i, x+CI_i]$
So I have N pairs of slightly different ($x_i,CI_i$), for $i=1,...,N$, due to the random nature of producing specimens
Now, I want to estimate my confidence on the mean of the mean properties of the N specimens, i.e., $E(x_i)$, the mean of the group of N specimens.

I thought to simply bootstrap on the N mean values of each specimen and build a confidence interval from that. But then I feel it will not be taking into consideration the information contained on the confidence interval of each of their individual mean estimates, which is an information I have.
I started considering making a weighted bootstrap, weighting each original sample by its confidence interval range (e.g. basically divide each $x_i$ by a normalized weight computed from their $CI_i$).
But I could not find a solid reference (paper, book) on that and since I am not a statistician I am afraid of getting into some pitfall.
What are your thoughts (and references) on that?
Thanks in advance!

Why don't you use parametric bootstrap to bootstrap new samples out of the distributions parametrized by x_i and the corresponding scale (related to what you call CI)? Then you can compute whatever statistic you want ...

And did you come across inverse variance weighting already? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting (not related to bootstrapping)

@Ggjj11 thanks for the insights! Regarding the inverse variance weighting, I did not know it, thanks for that. So from your inputs I envisioned two possible approaches: 1) instead of a bootstrap sample being made from random sampling with replacement from the set of N values of $x_i$, I would take one random sample out of each distribution parametrized by each pair of $(x_i,CI_i)$; 2) make a traditional bootstrap, using the original set of $x_i$, but then study the inverse-variance weighted average instead of the simple average. Would you know if one is theorectically sounder?

I think it is important to note that you are trying to find an estimator $\hat{E}[y]=f(x_1[y],...x_N[y])$ where the $x_i=\hat{E}[y]$ are estimated mean values already. Now there is different choices for $f$ and they may result in a higher or lower variance $Var[\hat{E}[y]]$. The least variance of the mean estimator will be given by inverse variance weighting (which also gives you a formula for the variance of the estimated mean). You will directly be able to see it in simulations as well e.g. (x_1=20, sigma(x_1) =60), (x_2=70, sigma(x_2)=1) should intuitively have a better estimate around 70

Also look for sensor data fusion https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion

Thanks for your messages, @Ggjj11, they really cleared things up for me, especially the first and the one before the last. If you wish, you can post them in an answer and I will accept it as so, as I think they wraps things up.
I gave this a good thought and decided to go for the parametric bootstrap you suggested in the first post. One of the things I want to study is how the size N of the initial set of means ${x_1[y],...,x_N[y]}$ affects the precision of $\hat{E}(x)$. In a bootstrap framework I can easily study that by simulating different bootstrap sample sizes.
